# Angular: Displaying target URL when resolve fails

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a simple resolver for a route like `/orders/first`:

```
resolve(): Promise<Order> {
    return this.orderService.get()
        .then((response) => response.order)
        .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
}
```

I also have an error handler that redirects to an error page:

```
this.router.navigate(['/error'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

I want the URL to be `/orders/first` so if the user refresh he might be able to view the page. This also make back button return to an incorrect page (previous previous page)

The problem is that the resolver runs before route activation so the URL doesn't change.

Is there a way to do this?

---

EDIT:
Found this workaround:

1. Listen to router event `NavigationStart` and save route to a variable
2. Set location URL before redirecting to error page: `this.location.go(nextRoute.url);`
3. Redirect with `skipLocationChange` set to true

Comment: Hi Tzach. Can you provide a sample/gist with your implementation? I need to have the same behaviour in an app that you described.

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved this this way:

```
resolve(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
  return this.clientService.get(route.params.id)
  .catch( err => {
    const path = this.location.path();
    this.router.navigate(["/" + err.status], {  skipLocationChange: true })
    .then( () => {
      this.location.replaceState(path);
    });

    return Observable.empty();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationError, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class RouterService {

    private errorRoot: string;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private location: Location
    ) { }

    setRouteErrorHandler(errorRoot: string = '/error'): void {
        let errorRoute = null;
        this.errorRoot = errorRoot;
        this.router.errorHandler = (error): void => {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(errorRoot, { skipLocationChange: true })
                .then(() => this.location.go(errorRoute.url));
        };

        this.router.events
            .filter(next => next instanceof NavigationError)
            .subscribe((next) => errorRoute = next);
    }
}
```

And call `routerService.setRouteErrorHandler()` from AppModule constructor or APP_INITIALIZER