# Redirect if Resolve fails Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How Can I redirect to another page if the resolve fails in Angular 2?
I call this resolve for my Edit Page, but I want to handle the errors in the Resolve Page

My Resolve:

```js
 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<any>|boolean {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            if (route.params['id'] !== undefined) {
                this.dataService.getHttpEmpresaShow(this.endpoint_url_Get + route.params['id'])
                    .subscribe(
                     result => {                    
                            console.log("ok");
                            return resolve(result);                     
                    },
                    error => {
                return resolve(error);
            });
    }});
```

Comment: Related Github issue : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29089 - asking for parity with the equivalent feature new for Authguards in Angular 7.1 (https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/11/22/what-is-new-angular-7.1/)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just like [in the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard), calling `this.router.navigate(["url"])`... (think to inject `Router` in your constructor)

```js
class MyResolve {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable <any> {
    return this.dataService.getHttpEmpresaShow(this.endpoint_url_Get + route.params['id'])
      .pipe(catchError(err => {
        this.router.navigate(["/404"]);
        return EMPTY;
      }));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's really not convenient to have a **/404** route! Ideally, we should be able to keep the original url (e.g. posts/some-missing-id) and show an error component instead of original handler component. Is there any way to implement such mechanism to (globally) handle errors in resolve guards?

Comment: It's really convenient to have a 404 route ! Instead of having spaghetti code with `ngIf="error"` it is centralized. If you want to keep the url take a look at the [router documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) and [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)

Comment: This is a bad practise. I've never seen a backend web server ever redirect to a dedicated 404 webpage. So why do this on the frontend?

Comment: Redirection is only a backend concept. You can navigate tona dedicated 404 page without changing url.

Comment: Once you've modified the URL by redirecting to something else all context is lost for the user. The proper way is to throw an error in the resolver, and catch the error in your main component by listening to navigation events. The main component can then render a 404 message which persists the original URL.

Comment: Once again, **you can keep the url**.

Comment: I think you don&#39;t understand what is done here. If you have a router outlet that is made to display a single item, and when you don&#39;t find the item, you display a 404 message in the same place without changing the url. That&#39;s the exact behavior you talked about ! You just need to pass `{skipLocationChang:true}` as an option to `router.navigate(url, options)`. @cgTag

Comment: I came across this question and wonder if a router has 2 values to be resolved and hence two resolver. What if the first resolver fails and redirects while the second works fine or vice versa.

Comment: @n00dl3, did you try it yourself? skipLocationChang:true is not working in case of data resolver I dunno why. If the URL which you visit is first URL and resolved can't resolve data and redirects to 404, original URL not saved and always become just "/" root URL without path, this.router.navigate(['404'], {skipLocationChange: true}); doesn't help. Angular 4. Not sure if that's a bug of router or it's a feature...

Comment: Found a bit dirty but working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42055517/angular-displaying-target-url-when-resolve-fails   Still no idea how it can be done in a normal and simple way.

Comment: @cgTag well it would depend on how complex your application is. I think I'm going to adopt this global `/404` page and send people there if I don't have a better alternative. I have a complex responsive design and generally a 404 means either a bug / deleted data or someone tampering with the URL - so I have no problem doing this. Now for a website intended to be publically indexed it's probably a whole different story but that isn't the case for many Angular apps...

Comment: While this solution works it actually generates a `NavigationCancel` event something like `Navigation ID 5 is not equal to the current navigation id 6"`. I've filed an issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29089 regarding this, and hoping for a better solution overall that's properly supported now that Angular 7.1 supports essentially the same feature for AuthGuards.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the discussion, in particular to @VladimirTolstikov for the weblink he published: it gave me a starting point, then I made some changes and I finally got my own solution, which is this:
`this.router.navigate(['/page-not-found'], {replaceUrl: true}).then(() => this.location.replaceState(state.url));`. Basically I redirect to a 404 error page and then replace the weblink in the address bar with the original url, so that the navigation flow is coherent for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, if you want to apply a redirect strategy after failling for ALL of your resolvers, you can intercept a router event and apply redirect on a fail event. Here the code you can add in your AppComponent :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterEvent, NavigationError } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ){}


  ngOnInit() {    
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      this.navigationInterceptor(event)
    });
  }

  navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.router.navigate(["error"],{ queryParams: { redirect: event.url } });
    }
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if you have nested component routes that you want to direct to, you need to now the entire path to the result, where as a `redirectTo` in place takes the route you want, and is defined at the path level